# How to Bind JSON Data On Html input box using Jquery In Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Data: JSON Formate

When Click   Edit button then Modal POPUP open but Data is not bind with Input or dropdown. I am trying but can't find out where is the problem.

**Json:**

```
[
  {
    "Buildings": {
      "Campuses": {
        "ID": 3,
        "Campus_Name": "Dhaka"
      },
      "ID": 9,
      "Building_Name": "D",
      "CampusID": 3
    },
    "Campuses": {
      "ID": 3,
      "Campus_Name": "Dhaka"
    },
    "ID": 17,
    "Floor_Name": "1st",
    "CampusID": 3,
    "BuildingID": 9
  }
]
```

**OR**

```
"[\r\n {\r\n \"Buildings\": {\r\n \"Campuses\": {\r\n \"ID\": 3,\r\n \"Campus_Name\": \"Dhaka\"\r\n },\r\n \"ID\": 9,\r\n \"Building_Name\": \"D\",\r\n \"CampusID\": 3\r\n },\r\n \"Campuses\": {\r\n \"ID\": 3,\r\n \"Campus_Name\": \"Dhaka\"\r\n },\r\n \"ID\": 17,\r\n \"Floor_Name\": \"1st\",\r\n \"CampusID\": 3,\r\n \"BuildingID\": 9\r\n }\r\n]"
```

**View:**

[please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Eo0.png)

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
            $.getJSON("/SuperAdmin/Floor/GetAllFloorList",
                function (json) {
                    var tr;
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + "<a href='#' class='btn btn-success' onclick='EditFloorRecord(" + json[i].ID + ")' ><span class='fas fa-edit'></span></a> " 
                        $('table').append(tr);
                    }

                });
        });



            function EditFloorRecord(Floor_id) {
            var url = "/SuperAdmin/Floor/GetFloorInfoByFloor_Id?floor_id=" + Floor_id;
            $("#ModalTitle").html("Update Building Record");
            $("#SaveRecord").html("Update"); // Change Save message
            document.getElementById('showeditFloorID').innerHTML = '<input class="form-control" id="FloorId" name="ID" readonly ></input>'; //Floor Id Show  kora jay
            $("#AddOrUpDateModal").modal();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    response = data;
                    document.getElementById('getbyid').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response); //Floor ID 
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data); //parse use kora hoya say Text box ar sathay Bind korar jono
                    $("#FloorId").val(obj.ID);
                    $("#Floor_Name").val(obj.Floor_Name);
                    $("#CampusID option:selected").text(obj.Campuses.Campus_Name);
                    $("#CampusID option:selected").val(obj.CampusID);


                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your ajax response your are getting JSON Array as a response. So array should be accessed with index. And also key name is **Buildings**. So you should say obj.Buildings to access properties of buildings. For example if you want to access ID of Buildings then you should say Buildings.ID. Because your JSON is returning array , you should do like response[0].Buildings.ID to access your first building's data.

No need to convert response into JSON,  var obj = JSON.parse(data) like this.  Because your response is already JSON object. You can use data object directly.

Your JSON Response:

```
[
{"Buildings":{"Campuses":{"ID":3,"Campus_Name":"Dhaka"},
"ID":9,"Building_Name":"D","CampusID":3},
"Campuses":{"ID":3,"Campus_Name":"Dhaka"},"ID":17,"Floor_Name":"1st",
"CampusID":3,"BuildingID":9}
]
```

Did you try accessing like below? Here data is array. You can access with index. To get the first element in response array you can do like below.

```
data[0].Buildings.ID
data[0].Buildings.Floor_Name
data[0].Buildings.CampusID
```

Comment: when I click to edit floor record it pop up but data is not shown and how to I bind this ajax data with HTML id